# Don't get data when fetching

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an application where i use redux. 
Also i used to fetch data native `fetch`.

```js
return fetch("https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/image/random").then(res => res.json());
```

In my react component i used `useSelector` to get data. But i didn't get anything.

```js
 useEffect(() => {
    console.log(selector.data); // here i should get data
  }, []);
```

How to get data in my component?

**Demo**: https://codesandbox.io/s/nervous-rosalind-lp16j?file=/src/App.js:242-328

Comment: Hey @AskMen, How's it going, did you find my answer useful?. I've put some time into it :)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fetch the data into your `App` component. I had to do a little bit of refactoring to get there.

1. Moved the store to your `index.js` file.

```js
//index.js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import createSagaMiddleware from "redux-saga";
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from "redux";
import reducer from "./saga/reducers";
import rootSaga from "./saga/saga";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import App from "./App";

const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware();

const store = createStore(reducer, applyMiddleware(sagaMiddleware));
sagaMiddleware.run(rootSaga);

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <React.StrictMode>
      <App />
    </React.StrictMode>
  </Provider>,
  rootElement
);
```

2. Create a new `action` in `saga/actions.js` called `fetchDogs`

```
//sagas/actions.js
export const fetchDogs = () => ({
  type: "FETCH_DOGS"
});
```

3. Moved the reducer to a new file called `saga/reducers.js` and updated the `FETCH_DOGS` case to set `loading` to `true` when it's dispatched and "DOGS_RECIEVED" to store the links of images. You can ofcourse change the reducer according to your wish.

```
//sagas/reducers.js
const reducer = (state = {}, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "FETCH_DOGS":
      return { ...state, loading: true };

    case "DOGS_RECIEVED":
      return { ...state, dogs: action.data, loading: false };

    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default reducer;
```

4. Refactored `sagas/saga.js`.

```
//sagas/saga.js
import { put, takeLatest, all } from "redux-saga/effects";

function* actionWatcher() {
  yield takeLatest("FETCH_DOGS", fetchDataAsync);
}
function* fetchDataAsync() {
  try {
    const json = yield fetch("https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/image/random").then(
      response => response.json()
    );
    console.log(json);
    yield put({ type: "DOGS_RECIEVED", data: json.message });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}

export default function* rootSaga() {
  yield all([actionWatcher()]);
}
```

5. Finally, in the `App.js` imported `fetchDogs()` action and dispatched it in `useEffect`.

```
//App.js
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import { fetchDogs } from "./saga/actions";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";

export default function App() {
  const dogs = useSelector(state => state.dogs);
  const loading = useSelector(state => state.loading);

  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(fetchDogs());
  }, []);

  if (loading) {
    return "Loading...";
  }

  console.log(dogs);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Dogs</h1>
      <img src={dogs} alt="new" />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here's a link to the [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/cranky-kalam-6cg3m?file=/src/App.js:0-406).

Comment: could you take  a look please, thanks: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63345237/save-data-in-a-special-order-when-click-on-button . Will be very helpful